Spring Cloud Gateway - Unable to route - Servlet failed with an Exception
I am trying to create a microservice example with the following versions of the stack -
JDK - 11
Springboot - 2.7.18
Weblogic - 14.1.1
I have created and hosted a eureka server on server-ip:7223/BankingEureka/ address and is successfully showing the UI of the application and also I'm able to register the applications server-ip:7223/BankingEureka/eureka/.
I have a microservice hosted on the same weblogic with the address server-ip:7223/balances/**. This service is successfully registered on eureka as BALANCES-SERVLET shown below.

As in the above image, even an API-GATEWAY service is registered.
Here are the application.yml of both the service-
BALANCES-SERVLET application.yml-
spring:
  application:
    name: balances-servlet

server:
  port: 7223

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
      base-path: /actuator
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always

eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
    status-page-url: http://server-ip:7223/balances/actuator/info/
    health-check-url: http://server-ip:7223/balances/actuator/info/
    home-page-url: http://server-ip:7223/balances/
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://server-ip:7223/BankingEureka/eureka/

API-GATEWAY application.yml-
server:
  port: 7225
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: reactive
  application:
    name: API-GATEWAY
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: BALANCES-SERVLET
          uri: lb://BALANCES-SERVLET
          predicates:
            - Path=/api-gateway/balances/**
          filters:
            - StripPrefix=1
eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://server-ip/BankingEureka/eureka/
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    org.springframework.web: DEBUG
    org.springframework.cloud.gateway: DEBUG

My main issue is when I host the API-GATEWAY application in localhost and run the URL http://localhost:7225/api-gateway/balances/**, it is successfully routed to the BANKING-SERVLET hosted on weblogic. But as soon as I host the API-GATEWAY to the same machine on weblogic, with the context-root '/api-gateway', only with a different port (7225 instead of 7223), I'm getting the following error-
<Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101020> <[ServletContext[app:APIGateway module:BankingAppAPI-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war path:null spec-version:4.0]] Servlet failed with an Exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendContentError(ServletResponseImpl.java:768)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:826)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:743)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.handleErrorStatus(ErrorPageFilter.java:156)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:128)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:82)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:82)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3866)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3829)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:344)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.processSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2502)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2351)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2326)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2304)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1779)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1733)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:651)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)

I've tried removing the context-root from the API-GATEWAY application, having the same port of all the eureka-server, BANKING-SERVLET, and the API-GATEWAY and still there is no success.
I know the routes are correct as the logs of the API-GATEWAY application displays -
RouteDefinition BALANCES-SERVLET applying {_genkey_0=/api-gateway/balances/**} to Path
RouteDefinition BALANCES-SERVLET applying filter {_genkey_0=/api-gateway(?<remaining>/.*), _genkey_1=${remaining}} to RewritePath
RouteDefinition matched: BALANCES-SERVLET

I have no idea why it is still not routed to the correct path even though it is successfully working in localhost. I tried adding custom GlobalFilter bean to log the incoming and outgoing request  but the bean is not being registered while hosted in the weblogic.
